# AWS - DynamoDB - I can't deserialize complex object that include other complex object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, generics, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I've created class with generic convert and unconverd methods. I wanted to use it with my CRUD methods. Im using DynamoDB so it's necessery.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I did this other way, to every complex class I've created different Converter class.

That's how looks my generic converter:

```
public class ObjectConverter<T extends Object> implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, T> {

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


@Override
public String convert(T object) {

    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse JSON");
}

@Override
public T unconvert(String object) {
    try {
        T unconvertedObject = objectMapper.readValue(object, new TypeReference<T>() {
        });
        return unconvertedObject;
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse to JSON");
}
```

}

I think the problems is that Java can't recognize class type. Can someone help me? Or maybe I can't use generic class and I have to do this other way?